# Get contact info fail?

Tags: java, android, contacts

I am making the user choose multiple contacts whose phone nums/names I add into a LinkedHashSet in order to avoid duplicates. My for loop (looping through the linked hash set is not getting excecuted. I believe there is an issue with the contact information gathering although that part gets excecuted)

```
private static final int Req_Code = 1;

private LinkedHashSet<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
private LinkedHashSet<String> numbers = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fetchContacts();

    final Button sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String t = text.getText().toString();
            if(!t.equalsIgnoreCase("") && t != null){
                for(int i = 0;i > names.size(); i++){//After debud messages , the only part of the program not getting excecuted is this loop.

                    Log.i("shit", (String) numbers.toArray()[i] + "     " + (String) names.toArray()[i]);
                }
                text.setText("");
                numbers = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
                names = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            }
        }

    });

}

private void fetchContacts() {
    Log.i("shit", "fetching");
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phone.CONTENT_URI);  

    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, Req_Code);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == Req_Code) {

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

              Uri uri = data.getData();

              Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

              cursor.moveToFirst();
              names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

              cursor.moveToFirst();
              numbers.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)));

              fetchContacts();

        }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if(names.size() == 0 || numbers.size() == 0){
                fetchContacts();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0;i > names.size(); i++){
```

Seems to me that this loop should never get executed, as I'm pretty sure that a collection can't have a negative size...

Did you mean to use `<` instead?

Also, you shouldn't be calling `numbers.toArray()` and `names.toArray()` every iteration of the `for` loop. For larger collections this could get inefficient.